# How to extract the file size with du

Tags: shell, text-processing, disk-usage

I'm using `du` to get the file size of the result archive in a packager script:

```
> du -smh archive.zip
51M    archive.zip
```

I'd like to assign just the `51M` part to a variable, to be able to print:

```
Archive size: 51M
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
$ variable=$(du -smh archive.zip | awk '{print $1}')
```

#### Details

`awk` will parse the output breaking it up into columns. You want just the results from column #1. The $( .. ) code will run a command and return its results.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks, for the explanation in particular!

Comment: @Benjamin if this answered your question, please mark it as accepted. That's the way to say thanks on the stack exchange sites.

Comment: @terdon I [quite know that](http://stackoverflow.com/users/759866/benjamin?tab=questions), but had to wait for 10 minutes before the system allowed me to accept the answer!

Comment: @Benjamin Fair enough, sorry. I hadn't seen your profile and thought you were new to SE in general.

Comment: @terdon No worries, that's definitely annoying when people get their answer and walk away!

Answer (score 4):

Or use the `stat` program, if it's available (usually on Linux by default).  No human-readable K/M/G conversion, but it also doesn't require anything else to get just the number / has nice formatting options:

```
sauer@humpy:~$ stat -c "%s" /etc/passwd
2302
sauer@humpy:~$ stat -c "%n size: %s bytes" /etc/passwd /etc/shadow
/etc/passwd size: 2302 bytes
/etc/shadow size: 1389 bytes
```

Answer (score 3):

Awk is a bigger hammer than you need, use a knife and cut,

```
variable=$(du -smh archive.zip | cut -f1 )
```